# iOS: Custom UITableViewCell not showing data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I created `UITableView` inside my `UIViewController` and I built a prototype cell in the storyboard. I assigned tags for all the elements in the cell I want to change and I am changing them in the code.

When the `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is called, my data is processed and I can see a cell appear with the red background colour I set in storyboard, however the images or text is missing. I think the problem is with the implementation but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is what the storyboard looks like:

[image]

This is the relevant code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    if(tableView == youLikeTableView)
    {
        UIView* youLikeImageFrame = (UIView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
        UIImageView* youLikeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
        UILabel *youLikeNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:102];

        for(int i = 0; i < [youLike count]; i++)
        {
            youLikeImageFrame.layer.cornerRadius = youLikeImageFrame.frame.size.width / 2;
            [youLikeImageView setImage:[youLikeImages objectAtIndex:i]];
            youLikeImageView.layer.cornerRadius = youLikeImageView.frame.size.width / 2;

            youLikeNameLabel.text = [youLikeName objectAtIndex:i];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

And this is the cell appearing without the text or images

[image]

Comment: Your cell isn't initialized. Check in the mainStoryboard if the cellIdentifier is equal to the identifier you want to use.

Comment: It is the same. In the storyboard its also "CellIdentifier"

Comment: what's the cell's class? I'm assuming you have a separate custom-cell file?

Comment: The style is set as custom in storyboard. I don't have any additional files for the cell.

Comment: Create a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and add the UI elements (labels, buttons, etc) to that file. Then click the cell and add the class in the Identity Inspector.

Comment: Two things to try: Step through that code to see whether variables are being set correctly and use View Debugging to capture the screen and inspect which objects are being displayed.

Comment: Alghough I personally woudl always go for a subclass of UITableViewCell you don't necessarily need one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to add them as subview

```
[cell addSubView:youLikeImageFrame];
[cell addSubView: youLikeImageView]; and 
[cell addSubView: youLikeNameLabel];
```

just before

```
return cell;
```

Comment: If they weren't already there as subviews, `viewWithTag:` wouldn't work.

Comment: This actually fixed the problem. Thank you. I don't understand why they weren't added automatically as they were added in the storyboard on top of the cell, but it works now.

Comment: By adding them AGAIN you probably changed the subview heirarchy or the drawing sequence. Have a look at your current heirarchy and at the sequence. e.G. the background can be sibling to the other view elements but it must be drawn first. You achieve that by having the background above the others in the view hierarchy tree if they are on the same hierarchical level.

Comment: if you want to use the label and other ui object from storyboard , then i suggest you to use custom Class of UITableviewCell for you cell in storyboard.
Here, The ui objects in cell will acquire the property of the object with tag but will not add them in your cell.